# marginnote within figure caption

Tags: captions, marginnote

I have a marginnote within a figure caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics{a.png}
\caption{
  This image shows something unusual.
  {\marginnote{ORLY?}[0cm]}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This compiles fine (without the {} around the \marginnote it fails), but still produces an error in the logs (which is very annoying in a multi-user overleaf project):

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.16 }

? Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.16 }
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fragile command in a moving argument.

Either use the optional argument (without margin note) of `\caption` or prefix with `\protect`.

In the latter case, the margin note will also appear in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\caption[This image shows something unusual]{%
  This image shows something unusual.\marginnote{ORLY?}[0cm]%
}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\caption{%
  This image shows something unusual.\protect\marginnote{ORLY?}[0cm]%
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to protect endlines in order to avoid unwanted spaces. Also `center` is not really wanted in `figure` as it would add vertical space before and after the float.

[image]